Can't connect to local mongoDB from Docker Container
I have mongodb running in the host machine (Ubuntu 23.04) in the default port. I have set the bind_ip to be 0.0.0.0. In my docker-compose file, I have added
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

And, I have my mongodb URI as mongodb://host.docker.internal/mydbname. However, I get Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
I tried to change network_type as host, after that it started working but why is this host.docker.internal working? Kindly please help.
Edit:
This is the docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    image: test
    container_name: test
    restart: always
    build:
        context: .
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
       - "9345:5000"
    command: node app.js
    env_file:
      - backend/.env.production
      - frontend/.env.production


Please share the docker-compose.yml, or at least the block containing mongodb

Have added the docker-compose.yml file, however there is no MongoDB block because Im trying to connect to locally hosted MongoDB.

Would you be interested in seeing a solution that doesn't use docker compose?

podman pod
Docker compose is an old technology that allows packaging multiple containers into a unit. This has been largely replaced by podman pod, which provides everything that docker compose provides, except it also provides

SystemD unit generation -- make it run as service in systemd.
Kubernetes generation -- make it run on a cluster.
Rootless operation

It's also easier to use. To do what you're looking for you can do something like this. Note podman pod is just a shell command, no YAML needed (though there is a YAML method too).
#!/bin/sh

podman pod rm -f mongoapp;

podman pod create \
  --publish 27017 \
  mongoapp;

podman run   \
  --pod mongoapp \
  --detach       \
  mongo:latest;

Now you have a pod created running mongo. Anything in the pod can reach it. This is where you'd run your "backend"
podman run -i    \
  --pod mongoapp \
  alpine:latest /bin/sh <<EOF
     apk update;
     apk add mongodb-tools;
     mongodump;
     exit;
EOF

Exposing Ports
Generally when you put Mongo in a container, you don't want anything to access it. You want the backend in a container communicating to it privately, and you want to provide access to the backend. To do this, we change podman pod create to publish the port,
#!/bin/sh

podman pod rm -f mongoapp;

podman pod create \
  --publish 27017 \
  mongoapp;

podman run   \
  --pod mongoapp \
  --detach       \
  mongo:latest;

And now anything outside of it can access it as if it was running on the host (if your host has mongodump it should just work). You can even access it from containers outside the pod (since the port is published) by using host.containers.internal,
podman run -i    \
  --pod mongoapp \
  alpine:latest /bin/sh <<EOF
     apk update;
     apk add mongodb-tools;
     mongodump --host host.containers.internal;
     exit;
EOF


Thank you for your answer, but I wanted to know how we could do it using docker compose only

@Equation_Charmer at the least, create a mre https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example
